# When does PANDAS groupby key remain after resampling?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, resample

Python PANDAS groupby-resample seems to act differently depending on the following aggregate functions.
The aggregate max() keeps the groupby key but the aggregate sum() does not.
Could anyone help me to understand this difference?

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

ts_col = [datetime.datetime.strptime('2024-01-01 01:00:00','%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') + datetime.timedelta(hours=i) for i in range(4)]
sdf = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a','a','b','b'], 'B':[3,2,1,0], 'T': ts_col}, index=[0,1,2,3])
sdf
```

The input DataFrame is then:

```
    A   B                     T
0   a   3   2024-01-01 01:00:00
1   a   2   2024-01-01 02:00:00
2   b   1   2024-01-01 03:00:00
3   b   0   2024-01-01 04:00:00
```

Applying the sum() aggregate function:

```
sdf.set_index('T').groupby('A').resample('H').sum()
```

shows

```
                          B
A      T
a  2024-01-01 01:00:00    3
   2024-01-01 02:00:00    2
b  2024-01-01 03:00:00    1
   2024-01-01 04:00:00    0
```

but, applying the max() aggregate function:

```
sdf.set_index('T').groupby('A').resample('H').max()
```

shows

```
                          A     B
A      T
a  2024-01-01 01:00:00    a     3
   2024-01-01 02:00:00    a     2
b  2024-01-01 03:00:00    b     1
   2024-01-01 04:00:00    b     0
```

The only difference is the aggregate function. But, the latter kept the groupby key
as column but the former did not.

Comment: The difference between the two aggregation functions is whether `numeric_only=True` is the default or not. The default value of numeric_only=True also depends on the pandas version.

Comment: As you suggested, that option make the results to be same. Thanks.
By the way if we omit the "resample('H')" from the two codes, their outputs become identical again (without 'numric_only' options). I am curious what the 'resample' does to groupby action.

Comment: I confirm the comment from Panda Kim: it also depends on the version of pandas: for pandas 2.2.1 for example, the two functions aggregation functions sum() and max() give an identical result, which corresponds to the default value numeric_only=False.